# AsyncFileUpload within EditItemTemplate of ListView

Tags: c#, listview, file-upload

I'm having trouble handling an `AsyncFileUpload` control within an `EditItemTemplate` in a `ListView`.

How do I reference the the `AsyncFileUpload` control when handling the `OnUploadedComplete` event in the code behind file?

I know that I can reference it within the `OnItemUpdating` event for the `ListView` but since it's an `AsyncFileUpload` how do I upload the file before saving the updates to the `ListView` item?

Thanks

Comment: can you show some code? How can you tell UploadedComplete is fired before or after ItemUpdating/ItemUpdated?

Comment: I got it working if its in the itemTemplate but not if its in the editItemTemplate. Its not firing the UploadedComplete event.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it casting sender in the event handling code :

```
protected void AttachmentAsyncFileUpload_Complete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    var FileUploader = sender as AjaxToolkit.AsyncFileUpload;
    FileUploader.SaveAs("testuploadedfile.tmp");
}
```