# AsyncFileUpload Inside Listview Insert, Edit Itemtemplate and EmptyData Template won't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, asp.net-ajax

AsyncFileUpload is not working inside Listview Insert, Edit Itemtemplate and EmptyData Template.

**Above is my Client Side Functions**

```
function AttachmentUploadSuccessful() {
    debugger;
    var textError = $(".AttachmentError").text();
    if (textError.length > 0) {
        var text = $(".AttachmentError");
        text.innerText = text.textContent = textError;
        sender._onError(textError); // it will raise the OnClientUploadError event
        return;
    } else {

        //alert(" File attachment is uploaded successfully.");
        //CODE TO  REMOVE FILE AND BACKGROUND COLOR OF FILE UPLOADER
        $('.ModelBackgroundforCreateItem').hide();
        $('.PopupPanel').hide();
        var UploadControls = $('#<%= FileUpload.ClientID %> :input');
        UploadControls.each(function () {

            //$(this).val("");
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
        });

        //Updating Update panel by clicking button
        $(".RefreshList").click();
    }
}

 function AttachmentUploadFailed() {

    alert("An error occured while uploading  File Attachment. ");
}
```

**Markup in .aspx file**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table class="fileUpload" runat="server" id="FileUploadID">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="width: 350px; overflow-x: hidden;">
                            <asp:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload" ThrobberID="Throbber" OnClientUploadError="AttachmentUploadFailed"
                                OnClientUploadComplete="AttachmentUploadSuccessful" UploaderStyle="Traditional" UploadingBackColor="" Style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px;"
                                OnUploadedComplete="FileUpload_UploadedComplete">
                            </asp:AsyncFileUpload>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 30px">
                        <asp:Image ID="Throbber" ImageUrl="~/Image/AttachmentLoading.gif" Style="display: None; width: 20px;" runat="server" />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Trying to upload file Client side event `OnClientUploadError` is getting called 
Not able to understand why it is giving error.
same file upload on simple page and inside Update panel working but inside list-view it is giving client error.
Gone through above link issue not getting exact answer please help me out.

[How to find Ajaxfileupload control inside Listview When in Editmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554179/how-to-find-ajaxfileupload-control-inside-listview-when-in-editmode)

[AsyncFileUpload within EditItemTemplate of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598638/asyncfileupload-within-edititemtemplate-of-listview)

Comment: Are you doing anything in FileUpload_UploadedComplete

Comment: Yes . I am making database call to save the attachment and taking attachment id and storing it on page which will be used at the time of submitting the from .

Comment: does it *have* to be in an update panel?? i know the normal upload control wouldn't work but you said this one does. wondering. i've never used the AsyncFileUpload.

Comment: no need of update panel this async file upload control is already having update panel so there is no point of adding one more update panel as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Liquid answered your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems in the code you shared:

1. That line of code: `var UploadControls = $('#<%= FileUpload.ClientID %> :input')`
2. And you doesn't have a `ClientIDMode` property in your markup, so it's `Inherit`

These two problems have the same origin: you're using the `AsyncFileUploader` inside a `ListView`, so there will be more than one element in your page with the `FileUpload` id.

So, firstly you must change the function declaration to:

```
function AttachmentUploadSuccessful(sender, e) { // then you can get the sender
```

And then, to get the the `input`, you'll be using:

```
var UploadControls = $(sender._inputFile);
```

Finally, to fix the 2nd problem, you'll need to change the `ClientIDMode` property to `AutoID`, so the `AsyncFileUploader` will be able to properly find its referenced client members.